# Integer.parseInt() and Integer.toString() runtime

Tags: java, string, integer, tostring, parseint

Would the runtime of Integer.parseInt(String i) and Integer.toString(int i) both be O(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes both of them `Integer.parseInt("1000")` and `Integer.toString(1000)` have time complexity *O(N)*

- The internal code of `Integer.parseInt("1000")` reads the the strings char by char and covert to decimal in while loop
- The internal code of `Integer.toString(1000)` reads the integers and convert every digit to char and stores in `byte[] buf` then creates new string from the byte array

> Here is the code of [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l532):
>
> ```java
> int i = 0, len = s.length();
> int limit = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
> // some checks
> int multmin = limit / radix;
> int result = 0;
> while (i < len) {
>     // Accumulating negatively avoids surprises near MAX_VALUE
>     int digit = Character.digit(s.charAt(i++), radix);
>     if (digit < 0 || result < multmin) {
>         throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s, radix);
>     }
>     result *= radix;
>     if (result < limit + digit) {
>         throw NumberFormatException.forInputString(s, radix);
>     }
>     result -= digit;
> }
> return negative ? result : -result;
> ```