# How to split a string delimited on if substring can be casted as an int

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I am attempting to split a string into a list of strings delimited on the change of if a character can be casted numerically or not. To say it another way, I want to break my string up into distinct groups of numbers and letters. For added fun, I'm also trying to trim any leading 0's from each group of numbers. Consider the following example.

Say you're given `"aoeu01234stnh0987"` as your input. The output I want is `["aoeu", "1234", "stnh", "987"]`

I made a working example below, but it is somewhat long and confusing. It seems like there must be a better, more concise way to achieve this.

```java
private static List<String> fragmentString(String string) {
    char[] charArr = string.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder tempStr = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tempInt = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean wasPrevNum = false;

    for (char c : charArr) {
        boolean isNum = Character.isDigit(c);
        if (isNum) {
            tempInt.append(c);
            if (!wasPrevNum) {
                wasPrevNum = true;
                tempList.add(tempStr.toString());
                tempStr = new StringBuilder();
            }
        } else {
            tempStr.append(c);
            if(wasPrevNum) {
                while (tempInt.charAt(0) == '0') tempInt.deleteCharAt(0);
                tempList.add(tempInt.toString());
                tempInt = new StringBuilder();
                wasPrevNum = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (tempInt.length() > 0) while (tempInt.charAt(0) == '0') tempInt.deleteCharAt(0);
    tempList.add(wasPrevNum ? tempInt.toString() : tempStr.toString());
    return tempList;
}
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787099/how-to-split-the-string-into-string-and-integer-in-java) about using the `split()` method, but that solution only works for their very specific case and doesn't apply here. The `split()` method was the first thing I played with to solve this, but I couldn't figure out a regex, and now I'm questioning if this is even possible using `split()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution can be using regex. The regex, `\p{L}+|[0-9]+`, which means sequence of letters or sequence of digits, can be used to find the substrings.  Then, try to parse the found substring. If it is an integer, the leading zeros will be removed as a result of parsing and if the parsing fails, simply print the substring.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aoeu01234stnh0987";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+|[0-9]+").matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String substring = matcher.group();
            try {
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(substring));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(substring);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aoeu
1234
stnh
987
```

Comment: I object to the use of exception handling for flow control. Yes, it works. No, perfectly expected inputs should not be handled as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This example isn't much more concise than the code the OP posted.  The best I can say is that I'm not using an exception as a part of my processing.

Here are the results from one test run.

```
aoeu01234stnh0987
[aoeu, 1234, stnh, 987]
```

Here's the complete runnable example code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StringSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringSplitter ss = new StringSplitter();
        
        String input = "aoeu01234stnh0987";
        System.out.println(input);
        List<String> output = ss.splitString(input);
        String[] output2 = output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output2));
    }
    
    public List<String> splitString(String input) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (input == null || input.length() < 1) {
            return output;
        }
        
        char c = input.charAt(0);
        boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit(c);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(c);
        
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
            c = input.charAt(i);
            
            if (isDigit == Character.isDigit(c)) {
                builder.append(c);
            } else {
                addToList(output, builder, isDigit);
                builder.delete(0, builder.length());
                builder.append(c);
                isDigit = !isDigit;
            }
        }
        
        addToList(output, builder, isDigit);
        return output;
    }

    private void addToList(List<String> output, 
            StringBuilder builder, boolean isDigit) {
        if (isDigit) {
            output.add(Integer.toString(
                    Integer.valueOf(builder.toString())));
        } else {
            output.add(builder.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some delimiter characters to each group of symbols, and then split the string around these characters:

```java
String str = "aoeu01234stnh0987";

String[] arr = str.replaceAll("\\d+|\\D+", "$0::::").split("::::", 0);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [aoeu, 01234, stnh, 0987]
```

```java
// trim leading zeros from numbers,
// i.e. parse the integer value
// and return it back to the string
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i].replaceAll("\\d+", "").length() == 0)
        .forEach(i -> arr[i] = Integer.valueOf(arr[i]).toString());

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [aoeu, 1234, stnh, 987]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to split the string into string and integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420278/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the code I ended up using in production, just in case it benefits anyone; I know there are already some great answers, and I used information from some answers here to come up with this.

```java
private static List<List<String>> fragmentArr(String[] inputArr) {
    List<List<String>> fragArr = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.stream(inputArr).forEach(string -> {
        List<String> listToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+|[0-9]+").matcher(string);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            StringBuilder substring = new StringBuilder(matcher.group());
            while (substring.charAt(0) == '0') substring.deleteCharAt(0);
            listToAdd.add(substring.toString());
        }
        fragArr.add(listToAdd);
    });
    return fragArr;
}
```

I used a while loop to trim 0's instead of converting to int and converting back to a string for 2 reasons.

1. **Time Complexity** - If you convert data types for this problem, even using a `Big Integer` or by some other means, you're costing yourself efficiency. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782618/integer-parseint-and-integer-tostring-runtime) on the time complexity of converting to an int and back. Both `parseInt` and `toString` are O(n) operations where n is the entire length of the string. My while loop implementation is O(n) where n is the number of leading 0's.
2. **Number Format Exception** - If you are passed a string like `"0000000000000000000001000000000000000000000"`, an exception would be thrown if you try to convert the value to an integer to trim the leading 0's because this value is too large for the integer data type in Java. So this is an edge case to consider.

Here's a unit test.

```java
@Test
public void fragmentTest() {
    assertEquals(
            Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList("abc", "123", "dce", "456"),
                    Arrays.asList("123", "abcde", "444", "a")
            ),
            fragmentArr(new String[]{"abc123dce456", "123abcde444a"})

    );
    assertEquals(
            Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList("abc", "1000000000000000000000", "def", "29")
            ),
            fragmentArr(new String[]{"abc0000000000000000000001000000000000000000000def29"})

    );
}
```

Comment: This is good that you have posted your own answer in addition to the existing answers. More alternative solutions are there, more useful the page becomes for future visitors. What is not good, however, is that now you have unaccepted the originally accepted answer and accept your own answer. Any community does not appreciate it. However, you are free to do so. Anyway, wish you success!

Comment: Fyi, I lost reputation points to accept my own answer, so it's not for my benefit. No other answers optimally or entirely solve my prompt. The accepted answer before (yours) uses try for known input and uses type conversion for trimming 0's, and the regex doesn't handle some alpha chars, like "-", correctly, The one by Gilbert uses type conversion too. Lorem's that uses a stream to trim 0's is interesting but also uses type conversion, All answers fail to consider ints that are larger than 4 bytes. I respectfully believe my answer best solves the problem, and I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Refrencing the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.), "Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.", I am trying to be objective.