# Creating new strings from one string

Tags: java, string, split

I have following string:

```
+420354599951 [table] +420354599969 [table] +420354599969 [fax] +420354599969 [mobile]
```

I need to seperate it everytime when [table], [fax] or [mobile] occur.
So I need to create from this string 4 different strings:

```
+420354599951 [table]
+420354599969 [table]
+420354599969 [fax]
+420354599969 [mobile]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using the regex, `(?=\\+)` where `?=` specifies [positive lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+420354599951 [table] +420354599969 [table] +420354599969 [fax] +420354599969 [mobile]";
        String[] parts = str.split("(?=\\+)");

        // Display each element from the array
        for (String part : parts) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
+420354599951 [table] 
+420354599969 [table] 
+420354599969 [fax] 
+420354599969 [mobile]
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(str.split("\\]\\s*")).map(x -> String.format("%s]", x)).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Yes, that can be another way.

Comment: Well it's really the same way as this (slightly simpler regex, with different trade-offs). Which is why I left it as a comment.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Thanks for this addition. When a genius like you answers or comments, it helps many!

Answer (score 1):

Taking @ElliottFrisch's example one small step further, you can save the Strings in a `List` using the [Java Stream API Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) as follows:

```java
List<String> numbers = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\]\\s*"))
    .map(x -> String.format("%s]", x))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this purpose:

```java
String str = "+420354599951 [table] +420354599969 [table] " +
        "+420354599969 [fax] +420354599969 [mobile]";

String[] arr = Arrays.stream(str
        // replace sequences (0 and more)
        // of whitespace characters
        // after closing square brackets
        // with delimiter characters
        .replaceAll("(])(\\s*)", "$1::::")
        // split this string by
        // delimiter characters
        .split("::::", 0))
        .toArray(String[]::new);

// output in a column
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```yaml
+420354599951 [table]
+420354599969 [table]
+420354599969 [fax]
+420354599969 [mobile]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to split a string delimited on if substring can be casted as an int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334063/14838237)</sup>